# How to group a Box plot by the column names of a data frame in Seaborn?

Tags: dataframe, seaborn

I'm a beginner trying to learn data science and this is my first time using the seaborn and matplotlib libraries. I have this practice dataset and data frame :

[image]

[image]

that I want to turn into a box plot and I want the x-axis to have all of the column names and the y-axis to range from 0 - 700 but, I'm not sure what to do.

I tried using :    random_variable = sms.boxplot(data = df, x = ?, y = 'TAX')

which does give me the y-axis that is close to what I am looking for but, I don't know what the x-axis should be set equal too.

I thought may I could use the keys of the dataframe but, all I got was this mess that doesn't work:
random_variable = sms.boxplot(x = df.keys(), y = df['TAX'])

I want it to look like this but, I'm really lost on how to do this:
[image]

I apologize if this is an easy fix but, I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to display your data like that go with

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.boxplot(data=df)
```